# How to modify end of URL using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

Have an URL of type:

```
https://example.com/some/text/1,2,3,5
```

Need to replace the `1,2,3,5` part with some different parameters like `2,4,6`.

Can do it in code by saving the first part of the URL `example.com/some/text/` in the `data` property but that seems messy so. I'd like to do it through REGeX or via similar method so that don't have to save partial URL anywhere.

Comment: If the first part of the url is known, then you could do `window.location.href.slice(0, endOfConstantTextPosition) + variableOfNewStuff`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf

Comment: Thanks guys, this seems pretty much it. I'll get back to it in half an hour and try it out. Feel free to leave answers to get some points there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could substring it to replace it, or you could break the url apart, get rid of the end, add the new ending, and then join it back up.

```js
var test0 = 'https://example.com/some/text/1,2,3,5';
console.log( test0.slice( 0, test0.lastIndexOf( '/text/' ) + 6 ) + '2,4,6' );



var test = 'https://example.com/some/text/1,2,3,5';
//get rid of the "1,2,3,5"
var tokens = test.split( '/' ).slice( 0, -1 );
//add the new ending
tokens.push( '2,4,6' );

console.log( tokens.join( '/' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the @Joshua Moore's link I ended up doing this:

```
var oldUrl = 'https://example.com/some/text/1,2,3,5';
var newParameters = '2,4,6';
var newUrl = oldUrl.substr(0, oldUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1) + newParameters;
```